# Google Collections (Guava Libraries): ImmutableSet/List/Map and Filtering

Tags: java, performance, immutability, guava

Assume that you want to build a copy of an `ImmutableSet`/`List`/`Map` object but filter out some of the original entries. One way to implement that is the following:

```
ImmutableList.copyOf(Iterables.filter(myObject, myObject.EQUALS));
```

where `myObject.EQUALS` is a predicate for the `Iterables.filter()` operation. I think this is a pretty elegant and easy-to-read implementation. However, one builds two list objects (first through the `Iterables.filter(...)` call, second through `ImmutableList.copyOf(...)`) which is very inefficient.

Does anybody know of a more efficient way to do it?

I guess the best thing would be to add filter predicates to the `ImmutableSet`/`List`/`Map` builders so that the object must be constructed only once. But unfortunately there is no such parameter.

Comment: Perhaps you can use Predicates.equalTo() instead of implementing it :)

Answer (score 18):

The result of `Iterables.filter()` is just a view over the data in `myObject`: the new list is only built by `ImmutableList.copyOf()` using the filtering iterator provided by the `Iterable`

Comment: +1: this is little-known and frequently over-looked: `filter()` does **not** create a copy (with all the related advantages and disadvantages), it's just a view.

Comment: This is the same thing for Iterables.transform()

Answer (score 0):

Look at Guava's [Iterators](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r46/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html)

Specifically filter(Iterator unfiltered, Predicate predicate)

Comment: Well yes, that's used internally by `Iterables.filter()` :-)

Comment: Yep. You are right. Just looked at it. If in doubt I use always use the iterators but that is good to know (View).