# Filtering Guava Multimaps

Tags: java, guava

Is there a a built-in method or combination of methods to return a filtered view of Guava ImmutableMultimaps using predicates, like you can with regular maps?

There does not appear to be Maps.filter method that accepts an ImmutableMultimap as a parameter.  Looking at the API I could call asMap() and get a map based view of the multimap and perform the filter that way.  However, I need to return an ImmutableMultimap from my function and for obvious reasons there isn't a way to view a Map> as an ImmutableMultimap - without having to contruct a new Multimap.

Even if I could filter it as a Map and cast it back to an ImmutableMultimap since they are all just views (I think?), the filter methods would only let me filter on the collection as a whole not removing individual values.

Comment: Are you looking to filter on the Keys or the values?

Comment: I actually need to filter on both.  In one instance just on the keys, on the other a key and a value.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176918/google-collections-guava-libraries-immutableset-list-map-and-filtering to get some ideas.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Multimaps.filterEntries](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#filterEntries-com.google.common.collect.Multimap-com.google.common.base.Predicate-) was added to Guava in release 11.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of copying the complete immutable multimap, you coud try to use a ForwardingMultimap and apply the filter when the map is queried, e.g.

```
@Override
public boolean containsKey(@Nullable Object key) {
  if (!keyFilter.apply(key))
    return false;
  return super.containsKey(key);
}

@Override
public boolean containsEntry(@Nullable Object key, @Nullable Object value) {
  ..
}

@Override
public Collection<V> get(@Nullable K key) {
  if (!keyFilter.apply(key))
    return Collections.emptyList();
  return Collections2.filter(delegate().get(key), valueFilter);
}
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static <Type1, Type2> ImmutableMultimap<Type1, Type2> dFilter(
        ImmutableMultimap<Type1, Type2> data,//
        Predicate<Type1> predicate//
) {
    Multimap<Type1, Type2> result = HashMultimap.create();
    for (Type1 t1 : data.keys())
        if (predicate.apply(t1))
            for (Type2 t2 : data.get(t1))
                result.put(t1, t2);

    return ImmutableMultimap.copyOf(result);
}
```

**Is there a built-in method ...**

No.

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet.  That is essentially what I ended up doing, but I used the ImmutableMultiMap builder instead so I didn't have to create a Map and then recreate it as an immutable map.

Answer (score 0):

Upon reflection, I don't think there is a way to create a filtered view of an ImmutableMultimap for a very good reason.  If an object expects an ImmutableMultiMap, it would expect that object to not appear to change for the lifetime of the object.  Applying a filter, that could operate dynamically, would break that implied (or possible written for all I know) contract as it would appear that between calls to various methods the map had in fact mutated.